# Attaching Gdb to a running multi threaded process

Tags: c++, gdb

I am attaching a running process in linux platform using gdb.

```
gdb -p <pid>
```

Setting the breakpoint, say

```
b test.cpp : 23
```

Now continuing

```
c
```

After this when i perform some operation destined to attached process, getting the below error in gdb console:

> (gdb) c
>
> Continuing.
>
> [New Thread 0x7409fb70 (LWP 8530)]
>
> Cannot get thread event message: debugger service failed

Please help me how to proceed further.
Additional details:
Its ***icc*** compiler, compiling with ***-g*** flag enabled

Comment: Did GDB show any warnings when attaching to the process? What was *complete* output of GDB? (Please edit your question and show the entire session.)

Comment: "how to proceed further" - probably update gdb. What is your gdb version?